# Signing a string with HMAC-MD5 with C#

Tags: security, c#-4.0, hmac

I got the following HMAC key (in hexadecimal format):

52320e181a481f5e19507a75b3cae4d74d5cfbc328f7f2b738e9fb06b2e05b55b632c1c3d331dcf3baacae8d3000594f839d770f2080910b52b7b8beb3458c08

I need to sign this string:

1100002842850CHF91827364

The result should be this (in hexadecimal format):

2ad2f79111afd818c1dc0916d824b0a1

I have the following code:

```
string key = "52320e181a481f5e19507a75b3cae4d74d5cfbc328f7f2b738e9fb06b2e05b55b632c1c3d331dcf3baacae8d3000594f839d770f2080910b52b7b8beb3458c08";
string payload = "1100002842850CHF91827364";

byte[] keyInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
byte[] payloadInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);

var md5 = new HMACMD5(keyInBytes);
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(payloadInBytes);

var result = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

However, I am not getting the result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
byte[] keyInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
```

you need to convert key from a hex string to array of bytes. Here you can find example:

[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Answer (score 13):

when hashing with key HMAC md5

```
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
        // key
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(transactionKey);

        // Create HMAC-MD5 Algorithm;
        var hmac = new HMACMD5(key);

        // Compute hash.
        var hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(data);

        // Convert to HEX string.
        return System.BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```