# Javascript Authentication Framework for .Net (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, md5, hmac

i try to use the same cryptographic as described here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Security/MD5HashinginJavaScript.htm

This code is used at a Website, where i try to write a tool for.

I tryed debugging it in Visual Studio with the following code:

```
var hexcase = 0;
var b64pad = "";
var chrsz = 8;


CalcMD5PW();

function hex_md5(s){ return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function b64_md5(s){ return binl2b64(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function str_md5(s){ return binl2str(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * chrsz));}
function hex_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2hex(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function b64_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2b64(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }
function str_hmac_md5(key, data) { return binl2str(core_hmac_md5(key, data)); }


function CalcMD5PW() {
var count = 0;
var space = "\0";
var md5Key = "Test1";
var password = "Test22";
var passwrd;
var encryPw;

while (count <= (2048 - (password.length + 1))) {
    if (count === 0) {
        passwrd = password;
    } else {
        passwrd += password;
    }
    passwrd += space;
    count += (password.length + 1);
}

while (count < 2048) {
    passwrd += space;
    count += 1;
}

encryPw = hex_hmac_md5(md5Key, passwrd);




}
 function md5_vm_test()
{
return hex_md5("abc") == "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72";

}

 function core_md5(x, len)
 {
            x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
  x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;

  var a =  1732584193;
  var b = -271733879;
  var c = -1732584194;
  var d =  271733878;

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16)
  {
   var olda = a;
   var oldb = b;
   var oldc = c;
   var oldd = d;

   a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 7 , -680876936);
   d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 1], 12, -389564586);
   c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 17,  606105819);
   b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 3], 22, -1044525330);
   a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 7 , -176418897);
   d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 5], 12,  1200080426);
   c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 17, -1473231341);
   b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 7], 22, -45705983);
   a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 7 ,  1770035416);
   d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 9], 12, -1958414417);
   c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 17, -42063);
   b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], 22, -1990404162);
   a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 7 ,  1804603682);
   d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], 12, -40341101);
   c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 17, -1502002290);
   b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], 22,  1236535329);

   a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 5 , -165796510);
   d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 6], 9 , -1069501632);
   c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 14,  643717713);
   b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 0], 20, -373897302);
   a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 5 , -701558691);
   d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], 9 ,  38016083);
   c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 14, -660478335);
   b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 4], 20, -405537848);
   a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 5 ,  568446438);
   d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], 9 , -1019803690);
   c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 14, -187363961);
   b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 8], 20,  1163531501);
   a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 5 , -1444681467);
   d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 2], 9 , -51403784);
   c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 14,  1735328473);
   b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], 20, -1926607734);

   a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 4 , -378558);
   d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 8], 11, -2022574463);
   c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 16,  1839030562);
   b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], 23, -35309556);
   a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 4 , -1530992060);
   d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 4], 11,  1272893353);
   c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 16, -155497632);
   b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], 23, -1094730640);
   a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 4 ,  681279174);
   d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 0], 11, -358537222);
   c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 16, -722521979);
   b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 6], 23,  76029189);
   a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 4 , -640364487);
   d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], 11, -421815835);
   c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 16,  530742520);
   b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 2], 23, -995338651);

   a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 6 , -198630844);
   d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 7], 10,  1126891415);
   c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 15, -1416354905);
   b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 5], 21, -57434055);
   a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 6 ,  1700485571);
   d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 3], 10, -1894986606);
   c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 15, -1051523);
   b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 1], 21, -2054922799);
   a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 6 ,  1873313359);
   d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], 10, -30611744);
   c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 15, -1560198380);
   b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], 21,  1309151649);
   a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 6 , -145523070);
   d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], 10, -1120210379);
   c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 15,  718787259);
   b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], 21, -343485551);

   a = safe_add(a, olda);
   b = safe_add(b, oldb);
   c = safe_add(c, oldc);
   d = safe_add(d, oldd);
   }
  return Array(a, b, c, d);

}

function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t)
{
  return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s),b);
}
function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
 return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
 return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function core_hmac_md5(key, data)
{
 var bkey = str2binl(key);
 if(bkey.length > 16) bkey = core_md5(bkey, key.length * chrsz);

 var ipad = Array(16), opad = Array(16);
 for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
 {
            ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
    opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
  }

  var hash = core_md5(ipad.concat(str2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * chrsz);
  return core_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128);
}

function safe_add(x, y)
{
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

function bit_rol(num, cnt)
{
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

function str2binl(str)
{
 var bin = Array();
 var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length * chrsz; i += chrsz)
 bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / chrsz) & mask) << (i%32);
 return bin;
}

function binl2str(bin)
{
  var str = "";
  var mask = (1 << chrsz) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < bin.length * 32; i += chrsz)
  str += String.fromCharCode((bin[i>>5] >>> (i % 32)) & mask);
  return str;
}

function binl2hex(binarray)
{
var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
var str = "";
for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
{
            str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((i % 4) * 8 + 4)) & 0xF) +
            hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i >> 2] >> ((i % 4) * 8)) & 0xF);
 }
  return str;
}

function binl2b64(binarray)
 {
   var tab = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
   var str = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i += 3)
 {
   var triplet = (((binarray[i   >> 2] >> 8 * ( i   %4)) & 0xFF) << 16)
            | (((binarray[i+1 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+1)%4)) & 0xFF) << 8 )
            |  ((binarray[i+2 >> 2] >> 8 * ((i+2)%4)) & 0xFF);
   for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    if(i * 8 + j * 6 > binarray.length * 32) str += b64pad;
    else str += tab.charAt((triplet >> 6*(3-j)) & 0x3F);
  }
  }
  return str;
 }
```

and i end up with this hash: "e14948da52f8b93122716c2bfaee6a9d" for the Variables md5Key = "Test1" and password = "Test22"

Does anyone know how i can get to the same result in c#? (Console Application). Maybe there is a framework or i am only using the wrong c# function? (I tried it this way: [Signing a string with HMAC-MD5 with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415438/signing-a-string-with-hmac-md5-with-c-sharp))

Regards,

Hdrk

Comment: Why do you need to replicate the hashing on JS? Unless you're using the JS on backend, it means you're sending the hash through the internet. And MD5 is terrible for hashing passwords. You're better off just use proper pbkdf libraries from NuGet and skip the JS altogether.

Comment: Hello Martheen, thank you for your answer. I do not need to replicate it on JS, i am looking for working c# solution to get the same result as i get with the JS code. I tried it with multiple code snippets and always get an other result. The WebSite is hosted in local lan and i can not change it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning : Unless you're OP and handling this very specific situation, DO NOT use the following code. Instead, read about [secure salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). Even if you don't care about security, Microsoft already implemented a standard-compliant (so it's compatible with other language & framework implementation) PBKDF2 with easily reusable [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing).

You haven't implemented the custom password derivation from the JS version of `CalcMD5PW`

```
private static string ConvertedMD5(string transactionKey, string password)
{
    //The lengthening start here
    string passwrd = "";
    var count = 0;
    var space = "\0";
    while (count <= (2048 - (password.Length + 1))) 
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            passwrd = password;
        }
        else
        {
            passwrd += password;
        }
        passwrd += space;
        count += (password.Length + 1);
    }

    while (count < 2048)
    {
        passwrd += space;
        count += 1;
    }
    //the following are bog standard HMACMD5
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwrd);
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(transactionKey);
    var hmac = new HMACMD5(key);
    var hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(data);
    return System.BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```